# Android Studio - Offline Mode not working

Tags: gradle, android-studio

So I am trying to use AS 0.6.0 in offline mode and I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'AppName': Unknown Host 'services.gradle.org'
```

I have Android studio in offline mode but it still seems to be trying to connect to the internet to do a Gradle Project refresh. I don't have internet and I just want to write some code and be able to emulate it. Someone please help, I am about to stab my MacBook violently.

My Android Studio also doesn't like my local Gradle location.....I point to it in settings and it says the location isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to handle this is to go into Android Studio preferences > Gradle, and check  "Offline Work".

That may be what you mean by "have Android Studio in offline mode".  It is actually Gradle that is trying to get to the Internet though.